# Clearing parameters of a session

Tags: jsp, session

I have a login page where i take in the username and password. I have used `setAttribute()` in my servlet to set the username and in my jsp page I've used `session.getAttribute()` to retrieve the username and print a welcome message.

This is my code snippet in one page:

```
`<h2>Welcome <%=request.getParameter("uname")%>! Enter the numbers and the operation 
   that you want to perform: </h2>
   <% session.setAttribute("uname",request.getParameter("uname")); %>`
```

And this here is in my other jsp page:

```
`<h2>Welcome back <%=session.getAttribute("uname")%>! Enter the numbers and 
       the operation that you want to perform: </h2>`
```

With this, even if i try to log-out and login again, it either says Welcome with the same name as previous user or Welcome with a null.
How do i clear the session attributes or the session itself, so that every time a new user logs in it says Welcome *that user* and if the same user logs in again, it says Welcome back?

Answer (score 1):

`session.removeAttribute("attributeName")` will remove the attribute from session and `session.invalidate()` will invalidate the session.

Comment: Which is the appropriate place to remove the attributes or invalidate the session?

Comment: When you are logging out, you can invalidate the session. And clearing /removing the attribute is based on your logic. If it has to be removed only at the time of log out, then include it in your Log out code itself.

Answer (score 1):

no need of `session.removeAttribute()`
you can just call `session.invalidate()` and this will remove attributes and session